# Forms with routes in Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4.1, ruby-2.1

Rails 4.1, reaching the driver knowing edit and use _form.html.erb again. I tried to do the following:

```
<% = Form_for @user, :controller => "admin/users" do | f |%>


<button type='submit'>Guardar</button>

<% end %>
```

#Controller
  ===============

```
def new
    @user = User.new
  end




def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
          format.html { redirect_to admin_users_url, notice: "User #@user.name} was successfully created." }
          format.json { render :controller => 'admin/users', action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
      else
          format.html { render :controller => 'admin/users', action: 'new' }
          format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end 
    end   
  end
```

But it does not work I can not get to the route that is my controller   ("admin / users"), if anyone can help me

Comment: is this like a nested resource? could you post the controller code and the routing

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have your admin routes defined in your `config/routes.rb` like this:

```
# in config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end
```

See: [Rails Guide about namespaces in routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

Then this should work for an admin namespaced form in your view:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @user] do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

See: [Rails Guide about namespaces and form helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-namespaces)

Your controller code looks okay, but please ensure that the controller is namespaced too:

```
# in app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb
module Admin
  class UsersController
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: When you save the recording even I do not get the driver path (admin / user_controller.rb)